# Exponential moving average with Flink SQL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, moving-average, flink-sql, kafkaflow

I want to mimic an example of an exponential moving average with Flink SQL. The data is coming from a Kafka broker which I am connecting with Flink SQL. Is it possible to achieve exponential moving average?

I have tried simple moving average on streaming data but unable to mimic the exponential moving average